# Count number of times an element in column appears over timestamp

Tags: pandas, dataframe, time, count

For a given row in a Pandas `DataFrame` I need to count the number of times the current column value e.g. 'destination_address_IP' has occurred in the past (say) 2 seconds using the 'Time_stamp' column and put the values into a new column 'count'.

Comment: Can you please provide sample data, together with the expected result?

Comment: Welcome to SO.  Please review [ask] and create a [mcve].  SO is *not* a free code writing service, nor is it a tutorial website.

Answer (score 0):

You could do that as follows, by shifting the dataframe repeatedly. The underlying assumption is, that the dataframe is ordered by the timestamp column:

```
# define the threshold in milliseconds (2 seconds)
time_threshold= 2000000
df['ip_count']=1
df_shifted= df
# loop over the dataframe and shift it by one row
# until the time_threshold is violated for all rows
while True:
    # shift the copy of the dataframe
    df_shifted= df_shifted.shift(1)
    # check if time range is ok
    ser_time_diff= (df['Time_stamp'] - df_shifted['Time_stamp'])
    ser_in_time= ser_time_diff.dt.microseconds + ser_time_diff.dt.seconds * 1000000 < time_threshold
    if ser_in_time.any():
        # there are still rows left, where the shifted
        # frame's timestamp lies within the threshold
        # so we need to count the matches for those rows
        # if there are any
        ser_match= ser_in_time & (df['destination_address_IP'] == df_shifted['destination_address_IP'])
        df['ip_count']+= ser_match.astype('int')
    else:
        # none of the rows of the shifted df was within
        # the threshold of the original df
        # so further shifts will not change the result
        # anymore
        break

df
```

The result for my testdata looks like this:

```
                   Time_stamp destination_address_IP  ip_count
0  2019-09-17 19:20:45.093209          157.111.73.31         1
1  2019-09-17 19:20:45.297932              127.0.0.1         1
2  2019-09-17 19:20:45.750725          157.111.73.31         2
3  2019-09-17 19:20:46.787009          192.168.21.15         1
4  2019-09-17 19:20:47.601051           52.18.181.18         1
5  2019-09-17 19:20:47.863428           52.18.181.17         1
6  2019-09-17 19:20:48.418591           52.18.181.18         2
7  2019-09-17 19:20:48.596764           52.18.181.17         2
8  2019-09-17 19:20:49.057553          192.168.21.15         1
9  2019-09-17 19:20:49.153256          192.168.21.15         2
10 2019-09-17 19:20:49.712312              127.0.0.1         1
11 2019-09-17 19:20:50.000119           52.18.181.17         2
12 2019-09-17 19:20:50.248562           52.18.181.18         2
13 2019-09-17 19:20:50.603783           52.18.181.18         2
14 2019-09-17 19:20:50.921631           52.18.181.17         2
15 2019-09-17 19:20:51.366193           52.18.181.18         3
16 2019-09-17 19:20:51.528611           52.18.181.18         4
17 2019-09-17 19:20:51.773429           131.53.97.59         1
18 2019-09-17 19:20:52.618215          192.168.21.15         1
19 2019-09-17 19:20:52.936181           52.18.181.18         3
```

It was generated from this data:

```
import io
import pandas as pd

raw=\
"""Time_stamp                   destination_address_IP
2019-09-17T19:20:45.093209   157.111.73.31
2019-09-17T19:20:45.297932   127.0.0.1
2019-09-17T19:20:45.750725   157.111.73.31
2019-09-17T19:20:46.787009   192.168.21.15
2019-09-17T19:20:47.601051   52.18.181.18
2019-09-17T19:20:47.863428   52.18.181.17
2019-09-17T19:20:48.418591   52.18.181.18
2019-09-17T19:20:48.596764   52.18.181.17
2019-09-17T19:20:49.057553   192.168.21.15
2019-09-17T19:20:49.153256   192.168.21.15
2019-09-17T19:20:49.712312   127.0.0.1
2019-09-17T19:20:50.000119   52.18.181.17
2019-09-17T19:20:50.248562   52.18.181.18
2019-09-17T19:20:50.603783   52.18.181.18
2019-09-17T19:20:50.921631   52.18.181.17
2019-09-17T19:20:51.366193   52.18.181.18
2019-09-17T19:20:51.528611   52.18.181.18
2019-09-17T19:20:51.773429   131.53.97.59
2019-09-17T19:20:52.618215   192.168.21.15
2019-09-17T19:20:52.936181   52.18.181.18
"""

df= pd.read_csv(
        io.StringIO(raw), 
        sep='\s{2,}', dtype={
                'Time_stamp': 'datetime64', 
        'destination_address_IP': 'str'}, 
        engine='python')
```